# Получить длительность видео MX Player Android в Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Здравствуйте.

Не могу понять, как получить длительность видео. 
Есть апи https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api
Там есть описание:

> duration  Added in 1.7.23 Type: int
> Value: Duration of last played video
> in milliseconds. This extra will not
> exist if playback is completed.

Передаю так:

```
  procedure VideoDuration;
  begin
    Intent.setPackage(StringToJString('com.mxtech.intent.result.VIEW'));
    iDuration := -1;
    Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('duration'), iDuration);
    Label2.Text := IntToStr(iDuration);
   end;
```

Не получается, что делать?